# Sencha JSON Parsing - broken JSON?

Tags: json, sencha-touch, jsonp, extjs

I am having some problems parsing some JSON.

The guy who put together the server code assures me that everything is fine, but whenever I try to parse some JSON via the JSONP proxy in sencha touch, I get a warning "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined.". This says to me that the formatting is broken on the APIs end.

The example callback is: http://api.pickple.com/comment/list?post_key=201108240008&site_key=etnews_20110616&format=json      (sorry, there is some Korean in there)

and the code I am using to parse is:

```
Ext.define('Paythread.model.Comment', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['user_id', 'total_count'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://api.pickple.com/comment/list?post_key=201108240008&site_key=etnews_20110616&format=json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'result' 
        }
    }

});
```

I have tried this same exact code with a JSON file on the local side and everything worked fine, so I am about 95% sure that the problem lies in either how I am parsing it or the JSON returned itself.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running your JSON through a json formatter/validator like: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or http://jslint.com/

Comment: Thanks M69, it was indeed the horrible JSON that was screwing up the sencha touch proxy reader.

Answer (score 0):

The link you posted does not contain valid JSON. I'd start there.

The very beginning of the JSON is:

```
{
    "status_code": 200,
    list: { {
```

`list` must be in quotes to be a key in the JSON object, and the `{{` isn't valid. Do you want an array of objects? (`[{ ... }]`)

Also, many of the strings in the JSON (the comments, mostly in Korean) contain newlines. JSON can hold newlines, but they must be escaped. This is invalid:

```
{ "comment": "Hello there
What a nice day" }
```

This is valid:

```
{ "comment": "Hello there\nWhat a nice day" }
```

And last:

> I get a warning "Resource interpreted as Other but transferred with MIME type undefined."

This is probably because the URL you posted is identifying that resource as "text/html" in the Content-Type header of the HTTP response. It's definitely *not* HTML, so that's wrong, and if it is JSON (it looks like JSON) then it should be identified as such. (Which is probably why you get the warning, since it isn't.)

Comment: Working on changing it right now... at least I know what the problem is now. You can probably see that I am quite new to this. :)

Comment: One minor question... how is the "root" that the reader is looking for defined?

Comment: It is close. I've edited my post, I think if you fix those things, it should parse. Do you have control over the URL?

Comment: @Mavorus: I'm merely attempting to parse your URL's contents as JSON, which it is very close to, but not quite. Not sure what a "root" is in a JSON context, but it seems to have something to do with your framework.

Comment: in the reader that should interpret the JSON, a root is required as a starting point.. in this case would that be 'list'?

Comment: JSON has no concept of a "root" (except maybe the top-level object/array) — this is probably something to do with your framework. All I'm saying is that if that URL should be JSON, it isn't valid JSON. (And whatever "root" does mean to your framework is probably irrelevant if it can't parse the JSON in the first place.)

Comment: Yes that's correct... the root seems to simply be the name of the property that contains the row objects.

Comment: Ok, made changes to the JSON. It should be correct now.. but still doesn't populate anything/correctly show in a JSON formatter tool on chrome... any ideas?

Comment: @Mavorus: The bit about newlines in strings still applies. Also, you didn't need to surround the top-level object in an array, unless your framework requires that.